# asp:LinkButton with Javascript errors in an user control

Tags: asp.net, javascript, webforms

I have a asp.net page with some user controls in it. One of the controls is a search form that has its results populated into a gridview.

The gridview needs to have some extra columns that contain 3 LinkButtons that perform a url calculation and redirect to another page.

The reason that I chose LinkButton over HyperLink is that I wouldn't need to perform all url calculations before the user actually needs, since I have way too many search results and the calculation is a bit expensive.

So, my LinkButtons look nice except when I am using IE6. In this case I get a Javascript error: "Expected ')'" or "Expected ':'".

Has anyone seen this?

Comment: Post the relevant snippet of your markup and the rendered html.

Comment: So the linkbuttons trigger a postback for server-side to 'calculate' the URLs and then perform a Response.Redirect? I assume the linkbutton throws an javascript exception upon clicking? You might want to provide the rendered html source of the linkbuttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally realized that my problem was some jQuery code that interfered with the links, thus producing an error.

Comment: pablo, could you elaborate on what you did to resolve the issue.  I'm experiencing the same issue and it appears to be a conflict with jQuery, but so far I haven't been able to resolve it.  Thanks.

Comment: basically I removed anything that jQuery could be doing with the links on my linkbuttons. if jQuery does not touch the linkbutton then it works like a charm